# Unit testing Vue JS component that uses MSAL.js for authentication

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, azure-active-directory, vue-test-utils

I have a Vue component which uses the `created` hook to connect to AzureAD and authenticate a user

The code looks like this:

```
  created () {
    this.loginOnLoad()
  },
  methods: {
    async loginOnLoad () {
      this.authService = new AuthService()
      let user = this.authService.sso()
      if (!user) {
        this.loginFailed = true
        await this.login()
        await this.authService.assignAccessTokenToHeader()
        NotificationsService.successNotification('Logged in successfully')
      } else {
        await this.authService.assignAccessTokenToHeader()
        NotificationsService.successNotification('Welcome Back')
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, I'm trying to write unit tests using `vue-test-utils` and `Jest`, however, when I run the tests the result is saying that user login is required. This is due to me not having mocked the `loginOnLoad` method, however, before I do that I'd like to know if actually mocking that method is the right way to go i.e. `let loginOnLoad = jest.fn()` or that will take away the value of the tests?